# Tips for powerlifting with a knee injury

Tags: injury, knees

So I f@#$% up my left knee about 3-4 years ago playing basketball. About 2 years ago I started training for powerlifting quite seriously. Because of my knee injury I have to be really cautious of things like technique and it made me very aware of my body. Currently there's no real problem but I'm kinda concerned for the future. Now don't get me wrong here I love my knee but I just want to perfect working with it.

I'm looking for tips (personal experience is the best imo but not the only thing) or resources on training in general and more specific powerlifting.

Comment: If it's a real injury with long term damage and you want to compete at a high level, you need to get it evaluated. It's a referral, some imagining, and a consult with a sports medicine doc: relatively painless.

Comment: @EricKaufman I forgot to mention that because in my mind it's pretty useless. I went to the doctor and specialist and had some minor surgery but they told me to take it easy the rest of my life. So I'm past that stuff

Comment: @Gordijn_forsale - Ever hear of a second opinion?